# Sort a PowerShell hash table on a property of the value

Tags: sorting, powershell, hashtable

I'm having an issue sorting a hash table.  I've broken down my code to just bare necessities so as not to overwhelm anyone with my original script.

```
Write-Host "PowerShell Version = " ([string]$psversiontable.psversion) 
$h = @{}
$Value = @{SortOrder=1;v1=1;}
$h.Add(1, $Value)
$Value = @{SortOrder=2;v1=1;}
$h.Add(2, $Value)
$Value = @{SortOrder=3;v1=1;}
$h.Add(3, $Value)
$Value = @{SortOrder=4;v1=1;}
$h.Add(4, $Value)

Write-Host "Ascending"
foreach($f in $h.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value.SortOrder)
{
    Write-Host $f.Value.SortOrder
}

Write-Host "Descending"
foreach($f in $h.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value.SortOrder -descending)
{
    Write-Host $f.Value.SortOrder
}
```

The output is

```
PowerShell Version =  3.0
Ascending
2
1
4
3
Descending
2
1
4
3
```

I'm sure this is just a simple case of not knowing the correct usage of `Sort-Object`.  The sort works correctly on `Sort-Object Name` so maybe it has something to do with not knowing how to handle the `Value.SortOrder`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Sort-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849912.aspx) accepts a property name or a script block used to sort.  Since you're trying to sort on a property of a property, you'll need to use a script block:

```
Write-Host "Ascending"
$h.GetEnumerator() | 
    Sort-Object { $_.Value.SortOrder } | 
    ForEach-Object {  Write-Host $_.Value.SortOrder }

Write-Host "Descending"
$h.GetEnumerator() |
    Sort-Object { $_.Value.SortOrder } -Descending |
    ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Value.SortOrder }
```

You can filter using the [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Write-Host "Ascending"
$h.GetEnumerator() | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -ge 2 } |
    Sort-Object { $_.Value.SortOrder } | 
    ForEach-Object {  Write-Host $_.Value.SortOrder }
```

You usually want to put `Where-Object` *before* any `Sort-Object` cmdlets, since it makes sorting faster.

Comment: I've updated my question to use the code you mentioned but I still get the same output.

Comment: nevermind looks like I missed the period. I'll re edit the question back to the original.

Comment: btw this may be separate question but is there easy way to >= 2 or some other filter.

Comment: Yes, in very similar fashion with Where-Object. Add "| Where-Object { $_.Value.SortOrder -ge 2 }" before your | Sort-Object, without the quotes.

Comment: No need to use a script block. $h.GetEnumerator() | sort Name will do

Comment: @ThomasMaierhofer No. The user doesn't want to sort by a `Name` property. He wants to sort by a property on a property of the object being passed.

Comment: You're right. Seems that I haven't recognized the whole problem

Answer (score 4):

I was using a hash table as a frequency table, to count the occurrence of words in filenames.

```
$words = @{}
get-childitem *.pdf | foreach-object -process {
    $name = $_.name.substring($_.name.indexof("-") + 1, $_.name.indexof(".") - $_.name.indexof("-") - 1)
    $name = $name.replace("_", " ")
    $word = $name.split(" ")[0]
    if ( $words.contains($word) ){
        $words[$word] = $words[$word] + 1 
    }else{
        $words.add($word, 1)
    }
}
$words.getenumerator() | sort-object -property value
```

It's that last line that does the magic, sorting the hash table on the value(frequency).

Comment: That's a brilliant answer.  I've been poking around for a couple of hours and seen so many complicated answers, but this works perfect.  Well done!  I needed the sort in a hash table, but it was a simple matter to put $hashtable = {what you wrote} and it worked great.  Thanks so much.